# how do I make my program guess for the correct word?

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, solver

I am interested in doing some AI/algorithmic explorations. So I have this idea to make a simple application kind of like hang man, were I assign a word and leave some letters as clues. But instead of a user guessing for the word I want to make my application try to figure it out based on the clues I leave it. Does anyone know where I should start? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a database of words of the desired language (index wikipedia dumps).
That probably shouldn't exceed 1 million words.

Then you can simply query a database:

for example: fxxulxxs

--> **SELECT * FROM T_Words WHERE word LIKE f__ul__s**

--> fabulous

if there are more than 1 word in the return set, you need to return the one that is statistically the most used.

Another method would be to take a look at nhunspell

If you want to do it more analytically, you need to find a statistical method to correlate stems, endings and beginnings, or basically a measurement for word similarity.

Language research shows that you can easily read words when you only have the start and the ending. If you only have the middle, then it gets difficult.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been on lately. I like this approach because it seems to be more AI than an algorithm. I have a question, you mentioned getting Wikipedia dumps. how can I do this? thanks.

Comment: @user1656528:  See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Comment: Thanks I'll post another question if I need some more help.

Comment: That image and the 'research' surrounding it is not correct.  Annoying that the answer suggesting you query a SQL database with 1,000,000 entries is the best.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out some form of algorithm for measuring *edit distance*, such as [Damerau-Levenshtein distance (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance). That is typically used to find the one word among several that most closely matches some other given word.

It is used a lot for searching and comparison when processing DNA and Protein sequences, but might be useful in your case too.

Comment: @Kjartan: Just one question: How do you use this to compare one word with 1'000'000 words from a database ?

Comment: @Quandary Short answer: Search for a long time. I believe BLAST uses an algorithm similar to this when searching for protein or DNA matches: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST#Algorithm . Try putting in some combination of letters (representing proteins) in this search box: http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&PROG_DEF=blastn&BLAST_PROG_DEF=megaBlast&SHOW_DEFAULTS=on&SHOW_DEFAULTS=on&BLAST_SPEC=OGP__9606__9558

Comment: @Kjartan: Nah, never mind, stupid question. You either use the C# version and put it into a SQL server CLR function (SQL Server, Oracle), or you use the C version and write an extended stored procedure (PostGre/MySQL/Firebird).

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to build a data structure containing all the valid words and which can be queried easily to retrieve all the words matching the current pattern. Then with this list of matching words you can compute the most frequent letter to get the next candidate. Another approach could be to find the letter which will give the smallest next matching words set.

```
next_guess(pattern, played_chars, dictionary)
  // find all the word matching the pattern and not containing letters played
  // not in the pattern
  words_set = find_words_matching(pattern, played_chars, dictionary)

  // build an array containing for each letter the frequency in the words set
  letter_freq = build_frequency_array(words_set)

  // build an array containing the size of the words set if ever the letter appears at least once
  // in the word (I name it its power)
  letter_power = build_power_array(words_set)

  // find the letter minimizing a function (the AI part ?)
  // the function could take last two arrays in account
  // this is the AI part.
  candidate = minimize(weighted_function, letter_freq, letter_power)
```